# Error al instalar App windows forms en windows 7

Tags: windows-forms

Trabajo con C# y desarrolle una aplicacion Windows Forms cuya plataforma de destino es .net Framework 4.7.2, trabajo con Visual Studio 2019 para poder usar el conector de MySQL en los DataSet.

Cuando quiero instalar la aplicacion en windows 7 me manda a instalar el .net Framework 4.7.2 obviamente pero da error y si intento desde el sitio de microsoft no inicia la descarga. alguien sabe si en windows 7(que ya no tiene soporte) se puede instalar dicha version de net framework, o deberia bajar la version? (aunque deberia probar en mi proyecto si compilara)

[image: error]

Comment: La versión 4.7.2 es antediluviana ... deberías plantearte una versión más moderna del framework

Comment: Claro..pero una más moderna se instalará en windows 7 ?

Comment: Ah bueno, claro, que es Windows 7. Yo probaría entonces a descargar un instalador offline ... que no haya que descargar nada de internet

Comment: Ok gracias . Aunque según la documentación tanto .net 4.7.2 cómo 4.8 son compatibles con Windows 7 sp1.